# Accessing superview ScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, view, uiscrollview, superview

i added some views (every view has its own viewcontroller and nib) to an UIScrollView. How can I access the ScrollView from  within the UIViews I've added?

self.view.superview doesn't get me the UIScrollView properties. I need to disable scrollEnabled from within an UIView.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try (UIScrollView*)(self.view.superview).property to access the property you want :-)
It should work.

But maybe with an Delegate it would be better :-p

Good Luck !

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern Delegates are a fundamental concept of Objective-C programming, you should definitely look them up.

Comment: when using (UIScrollView*)(self.view.superview).property I only get the same UIView properties like before!

Comment: I think you should try a Delegate ;-) it's the best way in your case. Search for iphone delegate on google and you should find some tutorials.